# How to check type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I don't know how to check type of variable in haskell, Here i mean , when i read something from console with `getLine` ,however i expect it to be an interger but user can enter a string also,then i don't want my program to crash. For example if someone inputs a string and i try to convert it to `Int` then it will crash(exception) so i want to check whether it is convertable or not. How do i do that ? Thanks for any help :)

```
 main1 = do
        let g <- getLine
            k = g :: Int 
            if(k :: Int)
                then ........
```

Comment: Thats not how to convert string to int. Have a read about `read` in the IO chapter in learn you a haskell

Comment: Haskell was designed so that we don't need to keep type tags at runtime -- types can be erased during compilation, reducing the memory footprint. If really needed, we have `Typeable` to keep type tags around. For your problem, though, you don't need runtime type information at all, but to parse a string into a statically known type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Notice you *always* have a string from `getLine` - that's the type it returns.  If that string contains an ascii representation of a number then great and keep reading.

If you have a  string, `g`, and say `g :: Int` the compiler will simply so "no, you are wrong, that's a String".  You need to perform a translation - parse the string and compute an Int.  The most readily available methods are `read` in the Prelude and `readMaybe` in `Text.Read`.

Read will work but throws exceptions on invalid input:

```
Prelude> read "4742" :: Int
4742
Prelude> read "no" :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
Prelude> read "191andmore"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

The maybe variant is exception safe:

```
Prelude> import Text.Read
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe "181" :: Maybe Int
Just 181
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe "no" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe "211andmore" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
```

Comment: Is there any way to check if `::` will work before typing in `::` .  Like you typed in ` "no" :: Int` and it gives exception and i understand how Maybe works but without extra data constructor is it possible?

Comment: `::` is always evaluated at compile-time. It's a type annotation, so `a :: SomeType` is equivalent to doing `SomeType a = ...;` in Java or C++. It's going to either work or not work at compile-time.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo sorry for many questions,  As  Thomas M. DuBuisson  said if input is invalid and i try to use read then is their any safeway to avoid exception?

Comment: What non-exception result would you like if the user enters `"I will not enter a number"` for the input? Do you want zero? Negative one?   The value `Nothing` is the value you get with `readMaybe` and you can wrap that up however you'd like - for example `fromMaybe 0 (readMaybe "not a number")` will default to `0`.